# Separation of many signals all containing 1 common component

Tags: continuous-signals, decomposition

I have been struggling with a research question and would appreciate any pointers (or full solutions).

I have a data set of many (+/- 50k) observed - correlated - signals. These signals are known to contain 3 main components: S_total = S1 + S2 + noise.
S1 is common to all signals, S_total is observed.
For one signal, this could be visualized as:

[image: Decomposition of 1 signal]

A few signal together could look like this:

[image]

Note that the variation between these - simulated - signals is only coming from S2.

What method / algorithm would you recommend to obtain S1, which is common to all signals observed?

Many thanks in advance,

Bart

Comment: Do you have a signal model (i.e., a mathematical description of S_1, S_2 and the noise)?

Comment: Hello mateC, noise is a matter of debate, but let's assume Gaussian with 0 mean. These signals are typically described using a differential equation:

(dS_total(t))/dt=  (dS1(t))/dt+k2S1(t)-  k2/(1+k3/k4)*S_total(t)

Where k2 is the same for all signals, but k3/k4 results in the contribution of S2 which varies by signal.
Thanks for looking at this!